# How to make space between two text boxes in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need small white space between two text boxes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="input-group col-md-8">
    <span class="control-label">Product Name*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" id="productname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-md-4" style=>
    <span class="control-label">Short Name*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ShortName" id="shortname" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you need the space, what did you try to create space? what kind of space? margin/padding/&nbsp ?

Comment: Where is your second textbox?

Comment: Are you want space between the textbox? i mean in small device it having in two row .so there is add `mb-2` for below margin to each input-group

Comment: You can improve the question for more clarifications.

Comment: I tried using both padding and &nbsp it is working for my screen size but if the screen size decreases second text box is going next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you want space between the textbox? i mean in small device it having in two row .so there is add `mt-3`(margin-top) for below margin to each input-group

Is this issue?
[image]

Add `mt-3(margin-top)` to each `input-group` and also add a width to span for correct alignment like this `span{width:130px;}`

[image]

```css
span{
  width:130px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="input-group col-12 mt-3">
          <span class="control-label d-flex h-100 align-items-center">Product Name* &nbsp;</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Product Name" id="productname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group col-12 mt-3" style=>
           <span class="control-label d-flex h-100 align-items-center">Short Name* &nbsp;</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="ShortName" id="shortname" required>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are any changes. I would happy to change the answer:). For any issue comment here.

Comment: Thank you Rayees AC. Actually I want two text boxes side by side (in single row) but in between text boxes I need small white space and that should work for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use margin or padding class on your span element :

example

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="input-group col-md-8">
    <span class="control-label px-1">Product Name*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" id="productname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-md-4" style=>
    <span class="control-label px-1">Short Name*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ShortName" id="shortname" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/
>
> **Spacing**
>
> Bootstrap includes a wide range of shorthand responsive margin and padding utility classes to modify an element’s appearance.
>
> **How it works**
>
> Assign responsive-friendly margin or padding values to an element or a subset of its sides with shorthand classes. Includes support for individual properties, all properties, and vertical and horizontal properties. Classes are built from a default Sass map ranging from .25rem to 3rem.